# What is the principle that data is transferred to reader -> processor -> writer in spring batch?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

In my case, I'm implementing batch program that manages dormant accounts

My problem is this. The internal logic of the `processor` and the `writer` is not executed.

First of all, I thought about why the `processor` is not working. After thinking for a long time, I thought that the logic in the processor was not implemented because the data that the `reader` brought was not transferred to the processor.

For example, In `for` If the size of the repeat statement is 0, the repeat statement does not rotate at all

Usually, when transferring data from a function to a function, a parameter is used, but there is no such parameter in a batch

That's why I'm posting questions. I wonder how the data goes in order in the rotation of the batch leading to `reader` -> `processor` -> `writer`.

I think it's like bringing `Step` to `StepBuilder` and putting `reader`, `processor`, and `writer` together in one bundle and sending and receiving data in it. It is right?

Below is my code that has a problem. Please check if there is a problem with the report.

```
package com.capston.chatting.config.batch;

import com.capston.chatting.entity.Member;
import com.capston.chatting.enums.MemberStatus;
import com.capston.chatting.repository.MemberRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class InactiveMemberJobConfig {

    private final MemberRepository memberRepository;
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job inactiveMemberJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("inactiveMemberJob3")
                .start(inactiveJobStep())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step inactiveJobStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("inactiveMemberStep")
                .<Member, Member>chunk(10)
                .reader(inactiveMemberReader())
                .processor(inactiveMemberProcessor())
                .writer(inactiveMemberWriter())
                .allowStartIfComplete(true)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ListItemReader<Member> inactiveMemberReader() {
        log.info("InactiveMemberReader execution");
        List<Member> oldMembers = memberRepository
                .findByUpdateDateBeforeAndStatusEquals(LocalDateTime.now().minusYears(1), MemberStatus.ACTIVE);

        ArrayList<Member> collect = oldMembers.stream().map(member -> member.setInactive()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        memberRepository.saveAll(collect);
        return new ListItemReader<>(oldMembers);
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Member, Member> inactiveMemberProcessor() {
        log.info("test");
        ItemProcessor<Member, Member> memberItemProcessor = (member) -> {   // dose not working
            log.info("InactiveMemberProcessor execution");
            return member.setInactive();
        };
        return memberItemProcessor;
//        return new ItemProcessor<Member, Member>() {   // dose not working
//            @Override
//            public Member process(Member member) throws Exception {
//                log.info("InactiveMemberProcessor execution");
//                return member.setInactive();
//            }
//        };
//        return member -> {    // does not working
//            log.info("InactiveMemberProcessor 작동");
//            return member.setInactive();
//        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Member> inactiveMemberWriter() {
        log.info("InactiveMemberWriter execution");
        return ((List<? extends Member> members) -> {
            memberRepository.saveAll(members);
            log.info("Members : {}", members);
        });
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.2)

2022-08-22 21:57:29.812  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] c.capston.chatting.ChattingApplication   : Starting ChattingApplication using Java 11.0.12 on DESKTOP-SHB62PK with PID 18204 (D:\chatting\chatting\build\classes\java\main started by user in D:\chatting\chatting)
2022-08-22 21:57:29.813  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] c.capston.chatting.ChattingApplication   : The following 4 profiles are active: "google", "naver", "kakao", "local"
2022-08-22 21:57:29.835  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-08-22 21:57:29.835  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-08-22 21:57:30.203  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-08-22 21:57:30.235  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 28 ms. Found 4 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-08-22 21:57:30.549  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-08-22 21:57:30.554  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-08-22 21:57:30.554  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
2022-08-22 21:57:30.626  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-08-22 21:57:30.626  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 791 ms
2022-08-22 21:57:30.669  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-08-22 21:57:30.812  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-08-22 21:57:30.870  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-08-22 21:57:30.892  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
2022-08-22 21:57:30.970  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-08-22 21:57:31.021  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-08-22 21:57:31.272  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-08-22 21:57:31.276  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-08-22 21:57:31.700  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@62d2016, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@62c4efa9, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@56b3c5da, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@266f4945, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@73659a41, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@3cc99087, org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter@52b3aca9, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@44b457bc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@16cb2cdf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@fd87fe6, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5f5bda7b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@612557ba, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@19931dcc]
2022-08-22 21:57:31.707  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.c.batch.InactiveMemberJobConfig    : InactiveMemberReader execution
2022-08-22 21:57:31.724 DEBUG 18204 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        member0_.member_id as member_i1_3_,
        member0_.created_date as created_2_3_,
        member0_.login_id as login_id3_3_,
        member0_.login_pw as login_pw4_3_,
        member0_.name as name5_3_,
        member0_.role as role6_3_,
        member0_.score as score7_3_,
        member0_.status as status8_3_,
        member0_.update_date as update_d9_3_ 
    from
        member member0_ 
    where
        member0_.update_date<? 
        and member0_.status=?
2022-08-22 21:57:31.765  WARN 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.batch.JpaBatchConfigurer         : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs. To silence this warning, set 'spring.batch.jdbc.isolation-level-for-create' to 'default'.
2022-08-22 21:57:31.767  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: MYSQL
2022-08-22 21:57:31.774  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2022-08-22 21:57:31.807  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.c.batch.InactiveMemberJobConfig    : test   // next step is "InactiveMemberProceesor execution" log but not happened
2022-08-22 21:57:31.807  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] c.c.c.c.batch.InactiveMemberJobConfig    : InactiveMemberWriter execution
2022-08-22 21:57:32.001  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2022-08-22 21:57:32.022  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-08-22 21:57:32.024  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Starting...
2022-08-22 21:57:32.024  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : BrokerAvailabilityEvent[available=true, SimpleBrokerMessageHandler [org.springframework.messaging.simp.broker.DefaultSubscriptionRegistry@6a114117]]
2022-08-22 21:57:32.024  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.m.s.b.SimpleBrokerMessageHandler     : Started.
2022-08-22 21:57:32.029  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] c.capston.chatting.ChattingApplication   : Started ChattingApplication in 2.431 seconds (JVM running for 2.948)
2022-08-22 21:57:32.030  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2022-08-22 21:57:32.451  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=inactiveMemberJob3]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2022-08-22 21:57:32.731  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [inactiveMemberStep]
2022-08-22 21:57:32.938  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [inactiveMemberStep] executed in 207ms
2022-08-22 21:57:33.098  INFO 18204 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=inactiveMemberJob3]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED] in 573ms
2022-08-22 21:58:31.637  INFO 18204 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2022-08-22 22:28:31.643  INFO 18204 --- [MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 2, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
2022-08-22 22:39:54.662  INFO 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-22 22:39:54.662  INFO 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-08-22 22:39:54.663  INFO 18204 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

Comment: Don't you need `@EnableBatchProcessing` on your configuration class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved. In Step properties, the `allowStartIfComplete` property is given as true, so it works normally. But the question is still valid. I want to know how the data moves in the rotation of `reader`->`processor`->`wrtier`.

Comment: `I want to know how the data moves in the rotation of reader->processor->wrtier.`: You will find a detailed answer for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48092171/how-data-is-passed-from-reader-to-processor-and-to-writer/48694672#48694672